# Is there a VIM plugin for Windows that allows stepping through code?

Tags: vim

Many IDEs have functionality that allow you to understand code by "stepping" into function calls to look at the definition, and what the function actually does. It might also allow you to look at the values of defines (in C) and maybe color code blocks of code with a different background color if they are not built during compile time.

Is there any plugin that would allow VIM to be used this way?

Comment: You are asking about numerous different functionalities (debugging, semantic highlighting, `#define` resolution), which would ordinarily be a problem on its own, except that you're also asking us to recommend a plugin, and software recs are categorically off-topic here.  Try [vi.se] or [softwarerecs.se].  Be sure to make your question **more specific** before asking at one of those sites, or break it apart into multiple smaller questions.

Comment: What programming language you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what you ask for is an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).
But VIM is more an editor than an integrated development environment.

You can config VIM to act like an IDE:

- Use [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net) for function/variable definition jumping.
- Use [tpope/unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) for showing errors.

You should keep in mind that VIM is for editing.
Wish you good luck.